# extend images across slide active slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a website for a school project and we were asked to choose a company to design a mock promotional website for. I chose CVS but you could choose anyone. I managed to use a template which I had done completing some codecamdemy classes but the tutorials didn't appear to be helpful in regards to changing the length of the images. What I want to do is to extend the images called "nyse", "mentor" and "mountain" across the length of the whole slide container, but so far, when I change it, the image doesn't seem to do anything. Can anyone tell me where it is going wrong or where to put my code to extend the images? I have tried numerous divs but no luck so far. My code is presented below.

HTML

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300' rel='stylesheet'>
    <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
          <img src="img/cvs.png">
        </a>

        <div class="headerNi">
      <div class="container">
        <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
          <p><a href title="Click this link to view the scheme.">NIDC Graduate Scheme</a></p>
        </a>
        <div id ="headerMission">CVS Health's Northern Ireland Development Centre, which opened in 2012,<br> 
creates software solutions for all parts of the US company,<br>
with particular focus on internet and mobile applications.</div></div>


        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Staff Profiles</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Graduate Scheme</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">What we look for</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">

      <div id="nyse-slide" class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>CVS is now hiring</h1>
              <p>We will soon have a nice new building.</p>

              <ul class="get-app">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img src="img/nyse.jpg" width="540px">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div>

      <div class="slide slide-feature">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
            <br></br>
                <br></br>
                  <br></br>
                    <br></br>
                      <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                          <br></br>
              <a href="#">Accountability</a>
              <p>Take responsibility for your actions.</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 

      <div id="mountain-slide" class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Collaboration</h1>
              <p>At CVS, it's important to work together with your mentor!</p>

            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img src="img/mountain.png">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 


      <div id="pharm-slide" class="slide">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
              <h1>Tenacity</h1>
              <p>Be determined.</p>

              <ul class="get-app">
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="slide-img col-xs-7">
              <img src="img/pharm.jpg" width="540px">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>      
      </div> 

    </div>

    <div class="slider-nav">
      <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png"></a>
      <ul class="slider-dots">
        <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png"></a>
    </div> 

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
  .container {
  width: 960px;
  color: gray;
}

/* Header */

.header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;

  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;

  font-size: 17px;
  padding: 15px;
}


/* Menu */ 

.header .menu {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.menu > li {
  display: inline;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.menu a {
  color: #898989;
}

/* Dropdown */

.dropdown-menu {
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  min-width: 105px;
}

.dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #898989;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}


/* Carousel */

.slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 470px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.slide {
  background: transparent url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/feature-gradient-transparent.png') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
  .slide {
            text-align: center;
            height: 550px;
        }

        #nyce-slide{
            background-image: url('nsce.jpg');
        } 
        #pharm-slide-feature{
            background-image: url('pharm.jpg');
        } 
        #mountain-slide-feature{
            background-image: url('mountain.jpg');
        } 
.active-slide {
    display: block;
}

.slide-copy h1 {
  color: #363636;  

  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;

  font-size: 40px;
  margin-top: 105px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.slide-copy h2 {
  color: #b7b7b7;

  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;

  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.slide-copy p {
  color: #959595;
  font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  font-size: 1.15em;
  line-height: 1.75em;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 16px;
}

.slide-img {
  text-align: right;
}

/* Slide feature */

.slide-feature {
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url('http://devonsstudio.com/businesspeople.png');
  height: 550px;
}

.slide-feature img {
  margin-top: 112px;
  margin-bottom: 28px;
}

.slide-feature a {
  display: block;
  color: #6fc5e0;

  font-family: "HelveticaNeueMdCn", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;

  font-size: 20px;
}
.slide-feature p {
color: red;
}

.slider-nav {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 80px;

}

.arrow-prev {
  margin-right: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.arrow-next {
  margin-left: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 9px;
}

.slider-dots {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.slider-dots li {
  color: #bbbcbc;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.slider-dots li.active-dot {
  color: #363636;
}

/* App links */

.get-app {
  list-style: none;
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-top: 9px;
}

.get-app li {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.get-app img {
  height: 40px;
}
      color: #898989;
      padding: 6px 20px;
      font-weight: 300;
    }


    /* Carousel */

    .slider {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      height: 470px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

    .slide {
      background: transparent url('http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/feature-gradient-transparent.png') center center no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    .active-slide {
        display: block;
    }

    .slide-copy h1 {
      color: #363636;  

      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;

      font-size: 40px;
      margin-top: 105px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    .slide-copy h2 {
      color: #b7b7b7;

      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;

      font-size: 40px;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .slide-copy p {
      color: #959595;
      font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
      font-size: 1.15em;
      line-height: 1.75em;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      margin-top: 16px;
    }

    .slide-img {
      text-align: right;
    }

    /* Slide feature */

    .slide-feature {
      text-align: center;
      background-image: url('http://devonsstudio.com/businesspeople.png');
      height: 550px;
    }

    .slide-feature img {
      margin-top: 112px;
      margin-bottom: 28px;
    }

    .slide-feature a {
      display: block;
      color: #6fc5e0;

      font-family: "HelveticaNeueMdCn", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
      font-weight: 400;

      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .slide-feature p {
    color: red;
    }

    .slider-nav {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 80px;

    }

    .arrow-prev {
      margin-right: 45px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-top: 9px;
    }

    .arrow-next {
      margin-left: 45px;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin-top: 9px;
    }

    .slider-dots {
      list-style: none;
      display: inline-block;
      padding-left: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .slider-dots li {
      color: #bbbcbc;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .slider-dots li.active-dot {
      color: #363636;
    }

    /* App links */

    .get-app {
      list-style: none;
      padding-bottom: 9px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      padding-top: 9px;
    }

    .get-app li {
      float: left;
      margin-bottom: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    .get-app img {
      height: 40px;
    }
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
   var main = function() {
  $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
  });


  $('.arrow-next').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var nextDot = currentDot.next();

    if(nextSlide.length === 0) {
      nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
      nextDot = $('.dot').first();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });


  $('.arrow-prev').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
    var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

    var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
    var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

    if(prevSlide.length === 0) {
      prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
      prevDot = $('.dot').last();
    }

    currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
    prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

    currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
    prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
  });

}

$(document).ready(main);
```

Comment: when you say "extend the images across the width of the container"? what exactly do you mean? How do you want it to act when you click the $('.arrow-next') link?

Comment: Do you see how the image in the accountability section extends the whole size of the navigation slider? i basically want to extend the other images to do the same.

Comment: ok i updated my answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres a **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1t41paqy/1/)** (You only need to add your images URLS to the CSS)

The first thing you need to do is to add e.preventDefault(); to your click evennts like this:

```
 $('.arrow-next').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //..more code
 });

 $('.arrow-prev').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //..more code
 });
```

Then you need to give each slide a unique ID and give it a background for the image, just like you have a background for the .slide-feature like this:

HTML:

```
 <div id="nyce-slide" class="slide">
  <!-- ...code.. -->
 </div>

 <div id="mountain-slide" class="slide">
  <!-- ...code.. -->
 </div>

 <div id="mentor-slide" class="slide">
  <!-- ...code.. -->
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
       .slide {
            text-align: center;
            height: 550px;
        }

        #nyce-slide{
            background-image: url('nyce.jpg');
        } 
        #mentor-slide{
            background-image: url('mentor.jpg');
        } 
        #mountain-slide{
            background-image: url('mountain.jpg');
        }
```

Heres the final edit:

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
                <img src="img/cvs.png">
            </a>

            <div class="headerNi">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="#" class="logo-icon">
                        <p><a href title="Click this link to view the scheme.">NIDC Graduate Scheme</a></p>
                    </a>
                    <div id ="headerMission">CVS Health's Northern Ireland Development Centre, which opened in 2012,<br> 
                        creates software solutions for all parts of the US company,<br>
                        with particular focus on internet and mobile applications.</div></div>


                <ul class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Curriculum</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Staff Profiles</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">More <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Graduate Scheme</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">What we look for</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slider">

        <div id="nyce-slide" class="slide active-slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
                        <h1>CVS is now hiring</h1>
                        <p>We will soon have a nice new building.</p>

                        <ul class="get-app">
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div>

        <div id="accountability-slide" class="slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <a href="#">Accountability</a>
                        <p>Take responsibility for your actions.</p>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>      
        </div> 

        <div id="mountain-slide" class="slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
                        <h1>Collaboration</h1>
                        <p>At CVS, it's important to work together with your mentor!</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div> 


        <div id="mentor-slide" class="slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="slide-copy col-xs-5">
                        <h1>Tenacity</h1>
                        <p>Be determined.</p>

                        <ul class="get-app">
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/ios.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/android.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/windows.png"></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/blackberry.png"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div> 

    </div>

    <div class="slider-nav">
        <a href="#" class="arrow-prev"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-prev.png"></a>
        <ul class="slider-dots">
            <li class="dot active-dot">&bull;</li>
            <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
            <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
            <li class="dot">&bull;</li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" class="arrow-next"><img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/flipboard/arrow-next.png"></a>
    </div> 

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var main = function() {
            $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
            });


            $('.arrow-next').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
                var nextSlide = currentSlide.next();

                var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
                var nextDot = currentDot.next();

                if (nextSlide.length === 0) {
                    nextSlide = $('.slide').first();
                    nextDot = $('.dot').first();
                }

                currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
                nextSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

                currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
                nextDot.addClass('active-dot');
            });


            $('.arrow-prev').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var currentSlide = $('.active-slide');
                var prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

                var currentDot = $('.active-dot');
                var prevDot = currentDot.prev();

                if (prevSlide.length === 0) {
                    prevSlide = $('.slide').last();
                    prevDot = $('.dot').last();
                }

                currentSlide.fadeOut(600).removeClass('active-slide');
                prevSlide.fadeIn(600).addClass('active-slide');

                currentDot.removeClass('active-dot');
                prevDot.addClass('active-dot');
            });

        }

        $(document).ready(main);
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: I've inserted your suggestions but it still isn't working. and the demo fiddle doesn't show pictures. If I edit my code with where I added your suggestions, would you be able to tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: the demo doesnt show your images because I dont know what images you are using. You have to place the image's URL in the CSS section. Yes, you can go ahead and post what you have updated so far and ill take a look at it. Let me know when its updated.

Comment: The images I am using are just jpgs that I stored on the laptop I am using. But if you need to see something for yourself, you could use anything as a substitute I guess. I have now updated the code with where I thought you suggestions should go-Are they in the right places?

Comment: Seems Good. **[Check out this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1t41paqy/1/)**. I found some test images. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Your test images look good but whenever I paste the fiddle code into my Notepad++ file and then launch it, it doesn't render properly and is all over the place. Are you able to put your code into my question box and I'll see if I can get that to render properly? Also whenever I run it from the fiddle, the nav bar needs clicked twice before it will go to the next page. Do you know what may be causing this?